# TypeError: setCreateType is not a function error in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
import React from 'react';

export const AddChannel = ({ setCreateType, setIsCreating, setIsEditing, setToggleContainer, type }) => (
  <svg
    width='14'
    height='14'
    viewBox='0 0 14 14'
    fill='none'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    onClick={() => {
       setCreateType(type);
      setIsCreating((prevState) => !prevState);
      setIsEditing(false);
      if(setToggleContainer) setToggleContainer((prevState) => !prevState) 
    }}
  >
    
  </svg>
);
```

Here is my code where I am getting errors. I tried a lot but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add your code that calls the `AddChannel` component? That might be where the problem originates.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your compiler is expecting types to be defined for those props you are passing in but you haven't defined them. Typically this is because you are using typescript without doing the proper types required, try the following.

```
type AddChannelPropsType = {
    setCreateType: (type: string) => void,
    setIsCreating: (state: any) => void,
    setIsEditing: (editing: boolean) => void,
    setToggleContainer?: (state: any) => void,
    type: string,
}

export const AddChannel = ({
    setCreateType,
    setIsCreating,
    setIsEditing,
    setToggleContainer,
    type
}: AddChannelPropsType) => (
```

Comment: Actually I am importing this file into another .jsx file in my project.  But I can't resolve it

Comment: Not sure what you mean? are your files ending in .tsx (typescript JSX)?

Comment: all my reactjs components are in .jsx format. The link https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_medical_pager_chat/blob/master/client/src/components/TeamChannelList.jsx  where I imported the above code.

Comment: That is required in .tsx, i guess but not in .jsx

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error, using prop drilling, turned out `setCreateType` prop in the parent component was misspelled.

Parent component where the issue was corrected:

```js
import React from 'react'

import { AddChannel } from '../assets/AddChannel';

const TeamChannelList = ({children, error = false, loading, type, isCreating, setIsCreating, setIsCreatingType, setIsEditing }) => {
  if(error){
    return type === 'team' ? (
      <div className='channel-list-list'>
          <p className="team-channel-list__message">
            Connection error, please wait a moment and try again.
          </p>
      </div>
    ) : null
  }

  if (loading){
    return (
      <div className='channel-list-list'>
      <p className="team-channel-list__message loading">
        {type === 'team' ? 'Channels' : 'Messages'} loading ...
      </p>
  </div>
    )
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="team-channel-list">
      <div className="team-channel-list__header">
        <p className="team-channel-list__header__title"></p>
          {type === 'team' ? 'Channels' : 'Direct Messages'}
          <AddChannel 
            isCreating={isCreating}
            setIsCreating={setIsCreating} 
            setIsCreatingType={setIsCreatingType} **//replaced with setCreateType={setCreateType} to fix the issue**
            setIsEditing={setIsEditing}
            type={ type === 'team' ? 'team' : 'messaging' }
          />
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TeamChannelList
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was because `setIsCreating` was not passed in parents components

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).